# Parenthesis, Comma Operator and Ternary operator combination equivalent in java

Tags: java, c

Can any one explain what below statement is doing ? Actually I want to translate code shown [here](https://github.com/beaudu/weton/blob/master/weton.c) in java, so its real code

> `w = (m<3?y--,m+=13:m++,d+153*m/5+15*y+y/4+19*c+c/4+5);`

I searched a lot but not able to found what this statement is doing. Can anyone explain it and help me to convert it into Java code ? I never seen combination of Unary Operators in Ternary Operators in C language. Sorry for simple question if it is but I did not understand it.

Comment: @SouravGhosh If you have any idea, can you please help me ?

Comment: @UnholySheep and possibly all other operators, too.

Comment: Maybe read some basic C book or online stuff: Check for "ternary operator" and "comma operator."

Comment: its better if you let us know what you want to achieve(otherwise with out using above expression) so that we can help

Comment: Looks like it is written for code golf, I don't think this is real source.

Comment: @Lundin I edited my question and put the link from where I taken it, so its real source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
w = (m<3?y--,m+=13:m++,d+153*m/5+15*y+y/4+19*c+c/4+5);
```

Works out to be the same as this:

```
if (m<3) {
    y--;
    m+=13;
} else {
    m++;
}
w = (d + (153*m/5) +(15*y) + (y/4) + (19*c) + (c/4) + 5);
```

Now for the explanation.  There is an instance of the ternary operator here.  The second clause is an **expression** which allows for the comma operator, while the third clause is a **conditional expression** meaning it can't include the comma operator (not without surrounding parenthesis, at least).  This means that the first comma you see is part of the second clause while the second comma marks the end of the conditional.

So the expression with implicit parenthesis would look like this:

```
w = (((m<3)?(y--,m+=13):m++), (d + (153*m/5) +(15*y) + (y/4) + (19*c) + (c/4) + 5));
```

And the part that makes up the conditional is:

```
(m<3)?(y--,m+=13):m++
```

And because this is the left operand of the comma operator, the result of the expression isn't used so it can be pulled out of the larger expression:

```
(m<3)?(y--,m+=13):m++
w = (d + (153*m/5) +(15*y) + (y/4) + (19*c) + (c/4) + 5);
```

And the conditional can then be further translated into an `if/else` block as above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great, to the point explanation and java code. It really helps me and solve my problem. You save me, really appreciated, and happy for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try.

```
m<3?
```

Is essentially

```
if (m < 3)
```

If it evaluates as true, y is decremented and 13 is added to m.
If it evaluates as false, m is incremented and then I think that w is set to whatever the result of "d+153*m/5+15*y+y/4+19*c+c/4+5" is.

Answer (score 0):

You can de-obfuscate it quite a bit by dropping the conditional and comma operators:

```
if(m<3)
{
  y--;
  m+=13;
}
else
{
  m++;
}
w = d + 153*m/5 + 15*y + y/4 + 19*c + c/4 + 5;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I ended up the same code but unfortunately both gives different result. C code prints ~ Senen Pahing ~ while above code prints ~ Senen Pahing ~ for today's date.

Comment: @Smeet Yikes, should be fixed now.